# Decoding emojis from tweets in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, decoding, emoji

I have a simple python script that gets the text of a tweet.

However, emojis are somehow encoded, so they look like this in the output \xf0\x9f\x90\xa3.

Is there a way to find out what emoji this is from this output?

Comment: `import unicodedata; print(unicodedata.name(b"\xf0\x9f\x90\xa3".decode('utf-8')))` says `HATCHING CHICK`. Ist's hard to say more without knowing what exactly your script doing...

Comment: @mata It sounds like he's getting the text of a tweet and the emojis are being displayed as `\xf0\x9f\x90\xa3`, so it sounds like he wants to know what emoji that actually is...

Answer (score 1):

Odds are it's UTF-8 encoded (along with the rest of the data, it's just that ASCII text happens to be be rendered identically in ASCII and UTF-8).

If you have a `bytes` like `b'\xf0\x9f\x90\xa3'`, you'd just do:

```
b = b'\xf0\x9f\x90\xa3'
txt = b.decode('utf-8')
```

If you received it as a `str`, this is probably a mistaken decoding as `latin-1` or some other code page, so just undo it and redo with UTF-8:

```
b = '\xf0\x9f\x90\xa3'
txt = b.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
# If it's not latin-1, could be sys.getdefaultencoding()
```

Which gets an ordinal of 0x1f423 (my computer can't display it, or I'd have added it here), which is in the correct range for most of the emoji. [As noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36335848/decoding-emojis-from-tweets-in-python-3/36336015#comment60293884_36335848), [`unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) reports the character as a [`HATCHING CHICK`](http://emojipedia.org/hatching-chick/).